# MSBuild + .dbproj

Tags: msbuild

i am trying to deploy db project through msbuild.

i am getting below error

```
MSBuild - Deploy DB project
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
    /nologo
    /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\2\Test\ePlanner\Sources\WebSiteBuildTest\Database\ePlanner\ePlanner\ePlanner.dbproj"
    /m:1
    /t:"Deploy"
    /fl
    /flp:"logfile=deploymentdb.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal"
    /p:TargetDatabase="ePlanner3";"TargetConnectionString="Data Source=SACHIN-PC%3Buser=sa%3Bpwd=M0nday!";"DefaultDataPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA";DeployToDatabase=true
    /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\2\Test\ePlanner\Binaries\\"
    /p:Configuration="Debug"
    /p:RunCodeAnalysis="False"
    /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/53;InformationNodeId=10631;TFSUrl=http://sachin-pc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;"
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
    Switch: Source=SACHIN-PC%3Buser=sa%3Bpwd=M0nday!;
    DefaultDataPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA;DeployToDatabase=true
    For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help" 
    TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

Please help me out

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Build server, local machine?

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a .dbproj in MsBuild the machine needs to have VisualStudio with the database project components installed, something to do with licensing. I cannot tell from the error dump that you provided if this is what is causing you the issue but it solved our issue when building on our build server.

Answer (score 1):

You've got conflicting quotation marks in your command line:

```
/p:TargetDatabase="ePlanner3";"TargetConnectionString="Data Source=SACHIN-PC%3Buser=sa%3Bpwd=M0nday!";"DefaultDataPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA";DeployToDatabase=true
```

The `TargetConnectionString` property is completely surrounded in double quotes, but then you use double quotes to specify the connection string.  Try escaping the quotes for the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the project to .sqlproj. This new format provides a "Publish" MSBuild target. You just need to specify at SqlPublishProfilePath property a publish profile file with your deployment options.

Look that sample:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="ProjectsBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Defines a collection of projects to deploy -->
    <ProjectsToPublish Include="SQLServer.sqlproj">
      <Properties>SqlPublishProfilePath=myprofile.publish.xml</Properties>
    </ProjectsToPublish>
    <!-- Runs the target Publish -->
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToPublish)" Targets="Publish"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Visual Studio 2010/2012 needs the SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools - ) installed to understand .sqlproj. Your build server too. It will install the MSBuild .targets extensions that contains the target "Publish".

Publish profile example (it's a MSBuild project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CreateNewDatabase>True</CreateNewDatabase>
    <TargetDatabaseName>DB1</TargetDatabaseName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=server1\dev;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges>False</BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>False</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <NoAlterStatementsToChangeCLRTypes>False</NoAlterStatementsToChangeCLRTypes>
    <DropObjectsNotInSource>True</DropObjectsNotInSource>
    <DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode>False</DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode>
    <DeployScriptFileName>db1.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```